# Is the ring of octonions "commonly" used in Cryptography?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I've recently read ["Fully Homomorphic Encryption on Octonion Ring" by Yagisawa](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/733.pdf), which is based on octonion rings over finite fields.

Personally I've never encountered octonion rings in cryptography before.
 **Is there any example of them being used in previous work?**

Please don't mention the mentioned previous version of this scheme.

Comment: There is some security concern [here](https://webpages.uncc.edu/yonwang/papers/octonionAlgebra.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can’t remember having stumbled upon them in *RealLife™* cryptography either, but I am well aware of a somewhat older, related patent by the same author. (Which might or might not violate your *“Please don't mention the mentioned previous version of this scheme.”* depending on what you’ve previously been reading. The patent is titled “Schemes for signcryption” and dates back to 2012. The paper published before the one you’ve mentioned was “Fully Homomorphic Encryption without bootstrapping”, published in 2015.)

Anyway…

From what I’ve seen, “patents” related to cryptography are a good way to ensure that no one feels the urge to use your “invention” anytime soon – which might explain the (lack of) popularity of the term.

> Publication number: [US20140169556 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140169556)
>   Publication type: Application
>   Application number: US 13/995,312
>   PCT number: PCT/US2012/070369
>   Publication date: Jun 19, 2014
>   Filing date: Dec 18, 2012
>   Priority date: Dec 18, 2012
>   Also published as [WO2014098807A1](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2014098807A1)
>   Inventors: [Masahiro Yagisawa](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=ininventor:%22Masahiro+Yagisawa%22)
>   Original Assignee: [Empire Technology Development Llc](https://www.google.com/search?q=inassignee:%22Empire+Technology+Development+Llc%22&newwindow=1&hl=en&tbm=pts&gbv=2&sei=hS21VZKaJuLuyQPFmoCoDA&gws_rd=ssl)
>   Export Citation: [BiBTeX](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140169556.bibtex), [EndNote](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140169556.enw), [RefMan](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140169556.ris)
>   [Classifications](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140169556#classifications) (10), [Legal Events](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140169556#legal-events) (2)
>   External Links: [USPTO](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=20140169556.PGNR.), [USPTO Assignment](http://assignment.uspto.gov/#/search?q=20140169556), [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=2014169556A1&KC=A1&FT=D)
>
> ### Schemes for signcryption
>
> US 20140169556 A1
>
> #### Abstract
>
> Technologies are generally described for providing a signcryption scheme. In some examples, a method performed under control of a sender device may include calculating a public key of the sender device based on a system parameter, calculating a temporary public key of the sender device based on the system parameter, calculating a temporary common key of the sender device based on a temporary secret key of the sender device and a public key of a receiver device, calculating a ciphertext from a message based on the temporary common key and generating a signature of the sender device based on an intermediate parameter, the system parameter and the secret key of the sender device. The temporary secret key of the sender device, intermediate parameter and secret key of the sender device are engaged in a non-associative octonion ring.
>
> In some examples, a method performed under control of a receiver device may include calculating a public key of the receiver device based on a system parameter, calculating a temporary common key of the receiver device based on a temporary public key of the sender device and a secret key of a receiver device, deciphering the ciphertext based on the temporary common keys of receiver device, determining whether the digital signature received is generated by sender device. A temporary public key of the sender device, the secret key of the receiver device and the temporary common keys of the receiver device are engaged in a non-associative octonion ring.

Comment: *"Please don't mention the mentioned previous version of this scheme.”* refers to the direct predecessor of the linked scheme (FHE), which seem to have been broken on some conference. The patent you mentioned doesn't look like FHE and is a totally valid answer as it shows that there was some use of octonion rings and that others couldn't.

Comment: @SEJPM Well, in that case… glad I could help. ;)