# Sedenion based encryption scheme

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Octonion is largest among divisional algebra whose inverse exist. It is used for fully homomorphic encryption scheme. Sedenion is a non-divisional algebra whose inverse does not exist. Can we use it for designing fully homomorphic encryption scheme?

Comment: [Related](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27163/23623)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you refer to this octonion-based FHE scheme that appeared several times [on eprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/462). In my opinion, this is a very bad paper. It was posted on eprint several times (at least thrice), and broken in a short note at least once. There was obvious mistakes at least in the first version, which show that it was written without any concrete understanding of how security should be argued in crypto. It is very obscure, horrible to read, written in a poor format (in Word, with long lists of formulas, non-justified text, with huge matrices written component-by-component). Therefore, it could contain many more mistakes, but it is just too painful to read it and to seek those mistakes - this is the exact opposite of what must be done in crypto, where you want to be as clear as possible so as to make the security of your scheme also clear.

A [similar paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-45744-4_15) appeared at ESORICS this year. From what I've heard by some researcher that looked a bit at it, it might be that the scheme is somehow secure as long as only uniformly random plaintexts are encrypted - put differently, it is useless. I cannot think of any standard application of fully homomorphic encryption where this scheme would be useful, and this paper being at ESORICS seems more like a manifestation of the fact that no member of the program committee of this conference was a cryptographer this year. This is a good security conference, but without cryptographers, they cannot judge cryptography papers (by the way, other crypto papers in the conference were broken, with simple attacks that should never have been missed during the review process).

So, to answer your question, maybe you could. But you should probably not spend too much time trying to do so - a scheme based on sedenions would probably be even more useless than one based on octonions.